# Finding maximum supported storage for RAID controller (INTEL esb2)

Tags: raid, intel, supermicro

We have here a supermicro server with 24 SATA slots. It has an ESB2 onboard RAID controller with intel matrix storage manager rom v5.6.4.1002 and 6 SATA ports on the mainboard.

Here is the mainboard
http://www.supermicro.com/products/motherboard/xeon1333/5000P/X7DB8.cfm

I wanted to connect 6 4TB SATA HDD to the board and use the controller to give me a RAID5 of these drives. However the RAID device is only showing 2000-something GB available (should be something around 2TB).

Is there a limit for the maximum storage that can be attached to this controller? I couldn't find any information on supermicro page about that.

Comment: Where exactly are the "2000-something GB" shown? Operating system? In the firmware of the RAID controller?

Comment: There are several issues actually. 1st 4TB discs are in the martrix storage manager firmware only shown as 2TB discs and when adding the devices (even if using devices smaller than 2TB) and putting in the slices, the whole array capacity seems to cap at around 2600TB, that means it seems to be unable to address more than ~2TB. Is this possible?